# Calculate lift for every row and compare it with the average lift of region and year

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, nested-select

I have a table that looks like the one below:

| Shop | Year | Region | Waste | Avg Waste (Year,Region) | Lift | Column_I_want_To_Calculate (apply case when statements) CASE WHEN Lift > Avg(Lift) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, REGION) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021 | CA | 10 | 15 =>(10+20)/2 | 0.67 => 10/15 | 0.67 < (0.67+1.34)/2 = 1.005 THEN 0 |
| b | 2021 | CA | 20 | 15=> (10+20)/2 | 1.34 => 20/15 | 1.34 > (0.67+1.34)/2 = 1.005 THEN 1 |
| c | 2021 | FL | 8 | 8 => 8/1 | 8/8 | 8 = 8 THEN 0 |
| d | 2020 | LA | 25 | 22 => (25+19)/2 | 0.88 => 25/22 | 0.88 > (0.88+0.87)/2 = 0.875 THEN 1 |
| e | 2020 | LA | 19 | 22 => (25+19)/2 | 0.87 => 19/22 | 0.87 < (0.88+0.87)/2 = 0.875 THEN 0 |
| f | 2019 | NY | 35 | 35 | 35/35 | 35 = 35 THEN 0 |

So far I have calculated the columns *Shop, Year, Region, Waste, Avg Waste (Year, Region), Lift*. I want to calculate the one marked as **Column_I_want_To_Calculate**.

Briefly, it computes the average lift per Region and Year and compares Shops' `Lift` with the Average Lift of all shops in the same `Region` and `Year`. Then assigns the value 1 or 0 in case of a greater than statement.

So far I have tried (PostgreSQL),

```sql
SELECT  shop
        ,year
        ,region
        ,waste
        ,AVG(waste) over (partition by year, region) as "Avg Waste (Year,Region)"
        ,waste/avg(waste) over (partition by year, region) AS Lift,
        ,CASE WHEN waste/avg(waste) over (partition by year, region) > 
           (SELECT tab2.avg_lift 
            FROM (
              SELECT tab1.year, tab1.region, AVG(tab1.lift) OVER (PARTITION BY tab1.year, tab1.region) avg_lift
              FROM (
                  SELECT year, region, waste/ avg(waste) over (partition by year, region) AS lift
                  FROM main_table
                  GROUP BY year,region,waste
                  ORDER BY lift DESC
              ) tab1
              GROUP BY tab1.year, tab1.region, tab1.lift
           ) tab2
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Column_I_want_To_Calculate"
FROM main_table
GROUP BY shop,
         year,
         nomos,
         waste
;
```

However, the code above throws the exception

> postgresql error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: @forpas I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Looks like 22/25 should be 25/22, just like the rest: The number of waste and the average waste. Correct?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, my mistake. Ty for pointing it. I will correct it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one returns the required output based on your input:

```
SELECT  
        region
    ,   shop
    ,   waste
    ,   round(AVG(waste) OVER w,2) AS avg_waste
    ,   round(waste / AVG(waste) OVER w,2) AS lift
    ,   CASE
            WHEN waste > AVG(waste) OVER w THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS above_average
FROM    i
WINDOW  w AS (PARTITION BY year, region)
ORDER BY
    1,2,3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Frank. Top quality and nice use of ```postgresql``` language. Kudos and thanks for addressing the question.